# Question Regarding Continuous Random Variables - Ball Diameter

Tags: probability

Suppose the outer diameter or a certain ball bearing produced by a manufacturing process is normally distributed with a mean equal to 3.5 cm and a standard deviation of 0.02 cm. If the diameter of this type of ball bearing must be no less than 3.47 cm and no more than 3.53 cm to be usable, what percentage of the bearings produced by this process must be scrapped?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, just copying the bare problem formulation with no info from you is considered by many to be rude; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage that must be scrapped is $1-\frac{1}{0.02 \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{3.47}^{3.53} e^{-\frac{(x-3.5)^2}{2\,0.02^2}} dx$.

Alternatively, you could notice that $Z = \frac{X-3.5}{0.02}$ has distribution ${\cal N}(0,1)$ and figure out the answer from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you are going out to $\pm 1.5 $ standard deviations from the mean.  The probability of getting an acceptable ball bearing is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} 0.02} \int_{-0.03}^{0.03} dx e^{-x^2/(2 (0.02)^2} \approx 0.866$$

So the probability of gtting a failure is about $0.134$.